# Capturando el formato correcto de un DatePicker

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Tengo un problema al capturar y convertir la fecha de un DatePicker.
La selecciono en formato dd/MM/yy, pero al convertirla a String con el siguiente código:

```
ListaFechaCompra = Convert.ToString(listafecha.Date)
```

...me la imprime con el formato MM/dd/yy

Hay alguna forma de capturar el dato con el formato correcto?

El código completo sería:

```
public void GrabarButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var vListas = new Listas()
        
        {
            ListaName = listaComboBox.Text,
            ListaComercio = comerciosComboBox.Text,
            ListaFechaCompra = Convert.ToString(listafecha.Date),
            ListaTope = Convert.ToDouble(precio.Value.ToString())
        };
        App.DAUtil.SaveListas(vListas);
        Navigation.PushAsync(new Lista());
    }
```

Gracias

Comment: Saludos. Si el código que muestras es de C# mira en https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_ el tipo de Dato de fecha tiene su propio ToString(String formato).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, he ampliado la pregunta...he comprobado en la documentación a la que te refieres lo que comentas, pero no sé cómo implementarlo en este código...

Comment: en la parte de respuesta ya pusieron como usarlo.

Comment: Ah, gracias, cierto!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias aplicarle formato, como ser

```
ListaFechaCompra = listafecha.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Referencia a como armar el formato

[Custom date and time format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Si usas el formato estandar

[Standard date and time format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

usando por ejemplo [ToShortDateString()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=xamarinandroid-7.1)

la cultura que tenga aplicada la aplicacion al ejecutar lo va afectar

[Implementing Localization In Xamarin.Forms](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implemented-localization-in-a-xamarin-forms-app/)

Si se selecciona una cultura `es-es` tendras un formato de fecha, pero si usas `en-us` tendras otra